# Error with Confluent Kafka Azure EventHub Source Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, azure-eventhub

I am trying to consume data from an Azure EventHub to my Confluent Cloud Platform Kafka (installed on an AWS EC2).

However, the Confluent Control Center is telling me that my connector failed upon launching it and **reading the log output, I see the following error:**

```
[2021-07-15 21:46:16,362] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=EventHubsLinuxMetrics-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:184)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:290)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:319)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:249)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Found null value for non-optional schema
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.validateSchemaValue(AvroData.java:1207)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectData(AvroData.java:389)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectData(AvroData.java:352)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:89)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:63)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$1(WorkerSourceTask.java:290)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
```

The error in questions says: **Found null value for non-optional schema**.
This is my connector config:

```
 {
   "name": "EventhubLinuxMetrics",
   "config": {
     "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
     "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.azure.eventhubs.EventHubsSourceConnector",
     "kafka.topic": "linuxMetrics",
     "tasks.max": "1",
     "azure.eventhubs.sas.keyname": "<censored for security>",
     "azure.eventhubs.sas.key": "<censored for security>",
     "azure.eventhubs.namespace": "<censored for security>",
     "azure.eventhubs.hub.name": "linuxvmmetrics"
   }
 }
```

Is there anything wrong with my config? Is `localhost:9092` the correct value for the `bootstrap.servers` field?

Comment: The error is saying you got a null message from EventHubs, but the Avro schema for said message does not allow for nulls (is the data actually Avro?)... Also, `localhost` would refer to a local Kafka cluster, not Azure

Comment: The data is just a bunch of logs I am trying to ingest, and I believe the logs are in JSON format. Would I have to change that setting somewhere? Regarding localhost, would I need to replace it with the IP address of an azure eventhub?

Comment: You need to fix `value.converter`, then, yes

Comment: Ok, and would localhost need to be changed to the IP of the eventhub?

Comment: Assuming you arent actually running Kafka brokers where the Connector is running, then yes

Comment: So upon switching to the JSON Converter, I end up getting the samer error: `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Conversion error: null value for field that is required and has no default value`

How am I getting a null value from Azure?

Comment: I'm not sure how you get null. But if you want to ignore schemas, you need to use `value.converter.schemas.enable=false`